# cache mpeg files on page load, html + php

Tags: php, html, caching, jwplayer

I have a page with an ajax page prowser.
On two slides an embedded player will play an mpeg or flv video file.

First time the page is viewed the file will be loaded and on slow internet connections it will stop-start since is is beeing showen and loaded at the same time.

Can I auto-cache the two files on page load so that the are cached and ready when the visitor are ready to watch them?

Br. Anders

Comment: What kind of player are you using?

Comment: For flv I use a custom version of JW Media Player version (4.3) as a pluin for the CMS TYPO3. For MPEG-2 I am still looking for a good way to embed the files.

Comment: mpeg-2 player: I use the "cross browser" answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227971/problem-with-chrome-embed-windows-media-player - it works fine i FF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should take care the HTTP headers for cache control. Make sure the static files are being served with following header (use FireBug to verify):

> Cache-Control: max-age=3600

However, you do not have full control over caching, it's up to the web-browser to cache large files or not.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. My files are often more than 100MB. It is for 7 info-touchscreens (with a buildt in small PC) that will load the webpage each morning and let tourist click through the slides during the day. Instead of trying to solve the caching issue I have Dropbox installed on the info-touchscreens and linking to local files in Dropbox. No more need for caching since files will be stored locally on each machine.