# How can I hide the control bar of the "Windows Media Player" for Chrome and FF?

Tags: html, windows, google-chrome, browser-plugin, wmp

I want to play a WMV video in an HTML file. The video should have no control panel (play/pause, volume, ...). With IE it works perfect. But with FF or Chrome the control panel is still displayed.

```
<object 
  classid="clsid:22D6f312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" 
  codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,4,7,1112" 
  id="playFormTmpl:player1_1_content1_wmv" 
  name="playFormTmpl:player1_1_content1_wmv" 
  style="width:1360px; height: 768px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"
<param name="filename" value="content/files/1527.wmv">
<param name="AutoStart" value="1">
<param name="ShowControls" value="0">
<param name="uiMode" value="none">
<param name="PlayCount" value="1">
<embed 
  autostart="1" 
  playcount="1" 
  showcontrols="0" 
  id="playFormTmpl:player1_1_content1_wmv" 
  name="playFormTmpl:player1_1_content1_wmv" 
  pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/download/AllDownloads.aspx" 
  src="content/files/1527.wmv" 
  style="width:1360px; height: 768px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" 
  uimode="none">
</embed>
```

Interesting is also that the code above works successful on Linux with FF or Chrome, but not on Windows.

I have installed on FF and Chrome for Windows the plugin found on this page: http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/windows-media-player-firefox-plugin-download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer works on all browsers (IE, FF, Chrome) and on Win and Linux:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2531887/1465758